# How do I use my reset upload key in Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, keytool, android-app-signing

My app's keystore was lost, and I had to reset the key. The key was reset, and I have been trying to make it work but I get a fingerprint mismatch. Here is what I did:

Created a new keystore via keytool
imported .cer file to keystore
sign app with new keystore entry

I get a mismatch error where the SHA1 fingerprints don't match. Am I missing something here? I've been through the documentation and other questions on here, but nothing really mentions what I'm specifically not doing right.

I've never lost a keystore before so I'm clueless as to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: A mismatch means that the keystore you configured to sign your app is different than the one you used to reset the key in Play Console. Make sure it's the same keystore and that you only generated a single certificate in that keystore.